# How to contact a REST API from Azure

Tags: rest, azure, api, post, methods

Can someone suggest a way how can we contact a REST API(using POST method) from Azure and need to store the JSON response received from API in Azure storage. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: from which service?

Comment: I am not sure which Azure service to use to reach a REST API using POST method. I am planning to use the API response received as input to Azure Stream Analytics Job.

Comment: azure function would be the easiest route, maybe logic app